# MapInfo Decimal Coordinates

Tags: mapinfo, vba

I'm trying to take the coordinates from a map in Mapinfo through a vb6 application through the commands:

```
x = CommandInfo(CMD_INFO_X)
y = CommandInfo(CMD_INFO_Y)
```

The data called is supposed to have 6-decimal places:

```
x = 120.629523
y = 14.074766
```

But instead the command rounds off the data it takes to 3 places in x and 4 in y as seen:

```
x = 120.630
y = 14.0748
```

Is there any way to call the full data?

Comment: Can you show the exact code you use from VB to get the values?

Comment: x = CDbl(MapInfo.Eval("CommandInfo(CMD_INFO_X)"))
and y = CDbl(MapInfo.Eval("CommandInfo(CMD_INFO_Y)"))


 This is the exact code for VB6. The ones above is directly to Mapbasic. I also tried adding other commands but those barely change the result.

    x = CDbl(FormatNumber(MapInfo.Eval(("CommandInfo(CMD_INFO_X)")), 6))

    The mapinfo must be setup first though.


    Set MapInfo = CreateObject("MapInfo.Application")
   or 

  for 64-bit
  Set MapInfo = CreateObject("MapInfo.Application.x64")

Comment: I have added an example of how to use the Format$() function from VB6 below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print or view the floating number, MapInfo Pro often rounds the number down to 2-4 decimals.

You can force more decimals out of the number using the Format$() function:

```
Print Format$(x, "0.000000")
Print Format$(y, "0.000000")
```

Can you try this from VB6:

```
x = FormatNumber(MapInfo.Eval(("Format$(CommandInfo(CMD_INFO_X), " & Chr$(34) & "0.000000" & Chr$(34) & ")), 6))"
```

In this way you send the formatting request to MapInfo Pro

Comment: Tried it before actually. Placed it before and after the command. Doesn't work. The command still rounds it out and it just adds more zeros. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Thank you! It finally worked!